# What does get_elements_by_tag_name() in Selenium return?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to build a small reddit chat extractor as a little practice project, using Selenium for Python for Google Chrome. When I run the following code,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.reddit.com/chat/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout = 60)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'MessageInputTooltip--Container')))
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
print(links)
```

I get the following as output:

```
[
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="58020598cd778d692bbab9043a1bbc63", element="6b958fe3-e950-4ff6-8689-e7174231857b")>,
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="58020598cd778d692bbab9043a1bbc63", element="f55a9564-708c-4f0a-9bc1-bed1e4179bf1")>,
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="58020598cd778d692bbab9043a1bbc63", element="dddef953-6240-4c77-8216-e34fd4964294")>,
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="58020598cd778d692bbab9043a1bbc63", element="fd4fc436-3a9a-4af4-84b9-1ca6473aaa17")>,
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="58020598cd778d692bbab9043a1bbc63", element="b3fa9218-4164-4ba3-90d3-51f402d9c5be")>,
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="58020598cd778d692bbab9043a1bbc63", element="734b1a3b-f41a-4135-8a44-84bc08552b25")>,
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="58020598cd778d692bbab9043a1bbc63", element="ed49c27d-8380-4e5d-b2f7-38b5b9645b0a")>
]
```

I want to get the values of `href` attribute from the extracted anchor tags, but instead I'm getting a list of these random-looking strings, from which I can't get the `href` or its values. I've also tried using XPath, but it either gives the same result when I write it thusly: `links = //a[@href]`, or I get an `NameError: name chat is not defined` when I either specify any value for `href` or use the `contains()` method.

The [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_tag_name) specifies that the method returns a list of WebElements. What are they, exactly, and what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
```

SImply get the href attribute out.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!
Just a follow-up, what does the ```find_elements()``` return exactly? Not knowing that was the reason I couldn't think of your approach. Apologies for novice questions.

Comment: List of webelements.